# VBA error when trying to copy and paste from 1 tab to a new tab

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Hi I've written the following code:

I am trying to create a new tab based on the value of a certain cell (S2). I then want to copy the information in range D2:R34 to the new tab but when pasting I get the Error 9: Subscript out of range, can anyone please help me?

```
  Sub Save_data2()
'Copy A Range of Data
  Worksheets("ROI - Post Visit").Range("J30").Copy

'PasteSpecial Values Only
  Worksheets("ROI - Post Visit").Range("S2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Dim TabName As Range
Set TabName = Worksheets("ROI - Post Visit").Range("S2")

'Creat New Tab with name of property
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = TabName

Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set NewSheet = Worksheets("ROI - Post Visit").Range("S12").Value

'copy worksheet
Worksheets("ROI - Post Visit").Range("D2:R34").Copy

'Paste
Worksheets("NewSheet").Range("D2:R34").Paste
Worksheets("NewSheet").Range("D2:R34").Copy
Worksheets("NewSheet").Range("D2:R34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Hello @PGD15, is your worksheet named as "NewSheet" ??

Comment: @VijayRajendiran my new sheet will be named based on the cell value S2 in "ROI - Post Visit" tab. So it has many variables. Please note i've updated my code

Comment: @VijayRajendiran to add the issue is calling the new tab, From the Set NewSheet = Worksheets("ROI - Post Visit").Range("S12").Value onward i just cant paste in the new tab as I can't select it